# Scroll div vertically

Tags: html, css

I am facing the problem to add a vertical scrollbar to my `container` `.right-side`. Inside of the container two `div` placed `.svg-position`. The container `.right-side` usually contains SVGs, but in the example I used some text for understanding.

Here is my code:

```css
  .right-side{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    z-index: -1;
    margin-right: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  .svg-position{
      height: 800px;
      width: 700px;
      position: relative;
    background: rgb(97, 3, 18);
  }

  .svg-position:nth-child(2){
    background: rgb(blue);
  }

p{
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="right-side">
               <div class="svg-position">
                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                </div> 
                <div class="svg-position">
                      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                      </div>
            </div>
```

I have tried it here and it worked, but in my vs-code it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

.right-side{ max-height: 150px; overflow-y: scroll;}

Comment: use that overflow-y :scroll

Comment: i have fixed, needed to change some other properties.

Answer (score 0):

Add `max-height` instead of `height` to your class `.right-side`